# Illegal character in query: not a URL code point

Tags: validation

I have a validator problem:

Bad value http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700,800|Varela+Round|Architects+Daughter for attribute href on element link: Illegal character in query: not a URL code point.

But I have the follow code, no spaces anywhere:

```
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700,800|Varela+Round|Architects+Daughter/" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: did you try to replace the pipe (|) character with %7C ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

in the link href change | by %7C

Answer (score 1):

There are 2 ways to fix this validation problem:

1. URL encode the `|` (vertical bar/line) character in the `href` attribute of the `link` element (as `%7C`) :

   `<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700,800%7CVarela+Round%7CArchitects+Daughter" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`
2. Separate fonts inclusion with multiple `link` elements :

   `<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Dosis:400,700,800" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Varela+Round" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
   <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Architects+Daughter" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">`

Comment: escaping | with %7C works. The latter solution looks dirty.

Answer (score 0):

Avoid illegal characters such as empty space. For example, instead of `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter One" />` use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Carter+One" />`.